# Add Words to Android's UserDictionary

Tags: android

I want to add an entire medical dictionary to my android phone (Moto Droid). I would like to be able to send text messages and have the medical words be in the predictable text.

I've been trying to write a small app that would accomplish this, but everything I try the app crashes on startup. I've never written an app for a mobile platform so that is a first for me. Here is what is not working properly.

```
public class WordAdd extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    UserDictionary.Words.addWord( this , "newMedicalWord", 1, UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE_TYPE_CURRENT);
}
```

}

It seems so simple to do, yet I am so stuck. Thanks for any help you can provide.

**EDIT:** I should mention that I am getting this error for Android 2.1 in the AVD (virtual device).

**EDIT 2:** [User Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html) is found in the Android API. [addWord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html) is a static method. I don't declare UserDictionary because I just use the one static method. It's been ages since I developed anything in Java and this is my first attempt at any mobile development, so I don't know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Is "android" a product name? Many people, like me!, might be confused by the reference. The action sounds like it would be something for a cell phone; if this is the case, you should say so in the question!

Comment: I did mention the Motorola Droid. I guess I thought that would be enough info. Sorry about that.

Comment: Haha, easy there grandpa; it's a cellphone ;)

Comment: post the error that are getting..ie the logcat output

Comment: I am not quite sure hot to logcat the output. A google search didn't turn up any help. I feel like such a newb.

Comment: What is the logcat of the exception?

Comment: Hi All, I am facing an issue with UserDictionary and would appreciate your inputs [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124711/android-personal-dictionary-app-issues) ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file outside of the `<application>` element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a breakpoint at the start of your activity and stepping through the code with the debugger.  This should help you isolate whether that call is really what is causing the crash, and what the underlying exception is.

Answer (score -2):

mm mm where UserDictionary is defined? maybe you should just

```
UserDictionary = new UserDictionaryType();
UserDictionary.Words = new WordsType();
```

OR define in the class just under the class declaration the fallowing :

```
 static UserDictionaryType UserDictionary;
```

if that's the case it's obvious why your app crashed ... (do it on kernel mode and "Houston we got a problem" you cant access pointer that you didnt allocated memory for even in java which is managed code...  )

but again I am not familiar with your code show us where it defined and I would try to help you more ...

EDIT1: even if UserDictionary exists in the API you didn't declare on one...
you should declare somewhwere static UserDictionary ud = new UserDictionary();