# Include Word Suggestions in Android Keyboard

Tags: android, android-keypad, word-completion

Hi I want to include word suggestions in my custom keyboard.

e.g if I write **`wi`** it should suggest me whether you want to write "winner" "winks" "wilson" etc

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: i hope [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) will help.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include suggestions in Android Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031402/how-to-include-suggestions-in-android-keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the real answer to this question.

It was hard for me to find:

First you need to:

[Add Words to Android's UserDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888896/add-words-to-androids-userdictionary)

By having the words in the dictionary, they will show up in suggestions.

If you want to exclusively show your words however, then something like the auto-complete dropdown idea is a better fit (that the other answers linked)

Comment: So you have to manually add words first?  Seems inefficient, as there are thousands of words in the English language...

Answer (score 1):

You can search for source code for android keyboard that are having this suggestion bars, i.e. download source for android gingerbread 2.3 keyboard source code, as android is opensource you can get the code easily.

Comment: I dont think your answer help anybody!

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but "easily" is the wrong word to use here, as the process of analyzing AOSP code is time consuming.