# Custom keyboard Predictive text

Tags: android, android-keypad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include Word Suggestions in Android Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107435/include-word-suggestions-in-android-keyboard)

I have created a custom keyboard for Android which will be the default keyboard of my smartphone and it will work with any app.

Now I want to add a feature of predictive text in it so that during chat /messages/mail if I type "ki"  it will predict some words like "king" "killer"  "kite" etc

Please help me because I'm desperate to add this feature.

As a reference to what I want [click it](http://droidfanz.com/uploads/posts/2011-05/droidfanz_1304238032_smart-keyboard-pro-v4.0.1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `EditText`, you have to use `AutoCompletetextView` where you have to load options. This means that if user writes `ki`, all possible options will be loaded.

Reference: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/example-of-autocompletetextview.html

Comment: hi friend i am developing a keyboard which will work as  a normal keyboard not an app which will have a textview and on cliking text view u will get predictive list i want some thing like if u use sms app using android keyboard u wil see a list of predictive text in a single line.............Thanks for ur reply   Have a good day:)

Comment: plz reply if any one knows about it