# Disable misspelling flag of specific words in app?

Tags: android, spell-checking

Our company's name always comes up as misspelled (the red underline) when typed into EditText fields in our app. Is there a way I can disable the misspelling flag for a specific word to avoid this nagging feature?

And before someone suggests `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`, I would still like spellcheck to be available to that specific field, and only exclude our company name.

Comment: One solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888896/add-words-to-androids-userdictionary

Comment: @Richard This seems like the right way to go but some of it is deprecated and I can't figure how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it'll work, but you can try putting `android.text.style.LocaleSpan` over each occurrence of the company name, using `Locale.ROOT` (which has no language) as the target locale.

(Most of the time you encounter a `CharSequence` in a text view it can be cast to `Spannable`. If it can't, just copy its contents into a `SpannableStringBuilder`.)