# Android- detect any offline language dictionaries are installed

Tags: android, android-intent

First of all,thanks to everyone, who considers this post.How to detect whether any of the offline language dictionaries,say https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.colordict&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImxpdmlvLnBhY2subGFuZy5lbl9VUyJd etc.., are installed in android  device and if yes, how can I pass the word(for which the definition is required) programatically to the dictionary application.Please help me.

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2888896/2345913)

Comment: Hi, @CRUSADER, thank you, but do UserDictionary would give , definitions ,noun,adjectives etc.,?.I think it just helps in adding words,which is required to display while texting

Comment: Sorry, haven't worked on this stuff, Why not you check for yourself..And then post your comment.. Im  sure others will benifit..

Comment: well okay.Thank you for the effort. If I get the answer,surely I l update this post .Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally , I prefer a solution for my question, though cant be the exact solution for the question.I used the link, http://thesaurus.altervista.org/dictionary-android

and used the available package and accessed from my application by using intent.

Answer (score 0):

try this-
http://sourceforge.net/p/dictionarymid/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Android/

might be it will be useful for you,good luck