# Android Personal Dictionary App Issues

Tags: java, android, dictionary, words

I am trying to write a personal dictionary application on android platform.
There are standard features like add,edit,delete.
I will be creating a personal application database to keep track of words.
Once the word is added in the personal dictionary; it should appear in the auto suggest when user is typing it in messaging/mail apps.
I looked at the following code snippet and tried to incorporate in my app:

```
UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "Joglekar", 1, "Jogl", getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
```

The code executes fine but the word does not appear in the auto suggest while typing.
I am testing on HTC One X as of now.
 Any leads on how to accomplish this ?? 
 Have a few follow up questions but will wait for this one to resolve. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file outside of the `<application>` element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"></uses-permission>
```

This solution worked at a similar problem, found here: [Add Words to Android's UserDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888896/add-words-to-androids-userdictionary)

Comment: Hi, I have this added. Can it be a concern with the underlining android implementation...I was trying to run it on ics on my HTC one x...